# how to i solve akeneo still loading after logged in main page?

Tags: php, installation, akeneo

[image]

> Here after akeneo installed 2.3 icecat version
>
> after logged in still loading ...

how do I solve this ???

in log file

> [2019-04-16 13:11:20] request.ERROR: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET //form/extensions" (from "http://ttttt.equpo.com/pim-community-standard/web/")" at /home/equpo/public_html/ake/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 144 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET //form/extensions\" (from \"http://tttt.equpo.com/pim-community-standard/web/\") at /home/equpo/public_html/ake/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:144, Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /home/equpo/public_html/ake/pim-community-standard/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:3128)"} []

Answer (score 1):

It appears as if you missed something during setup process.
Broken down, the [version 2.3 manual](https://docs.akeneo.com/2.3/install_pim/manual/installation_ce_archive.html) lists the following steps to setup an Akeneo system:

- `composer install --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist`
- `yarn install`
- `php bin/console --env=prod cache:clear --no-warmup`
- `php bin/console --env=prod pim:installer:assets --symlink --clean`
- `yarn run webpack`

Try those things, it should initialize everything - usually this helps already.

Comment: rror: It seems that your web server is not well configured as we were not able to load the frontend configuration. The most likely reason is that the mod_rewrite module is not installed/enabled.

--also in console

Comment: can i delete the files and  run cli  comments

or  run above the files

Comment: Just as your first comment indicates, you appear to be missing apache modules. Try running `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

Comment: how to use this in cpanel  (Actually cpanel not accept sudo comment)

Comment: It really depends on your hoster - it should have that enabled for you. You can check and see if you find the line `RewriteEngine On` in your .htaccess file.
Also check for errors in your apache log files, specifically the error.log file (usually you find it in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`)

Comment: i dont have apache (my istance run on nginx) so it's not a matter of mod-rewrite.