# Akeneo never stop loading when login

Tags: symfony, vhosts, akeneo

I've installed Akeneo Community Edition 3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 with the folowing:

- PHP 7.2
- Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
- yarn 1.16.0
- node v8.10.0

The installation seems to have been completed successfully, I can connect to mysql for creating the database, requirements tests have been passed.

I have configured the vhosts with:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName <my.server>

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/akeneo/web
    <Directory /var/www/html/akeneo/web>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/akeneo_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/akeneo_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The project is installed in /var/www/html/akeneo.

I can access to the home/login page, the css works correctly but when I enter admin/admin and try to connect, it never stop to load.

In the console, I can read 3 errors with 404 for vendor.js and main.js unreachable.

And in my symfony logs :

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /dist/main.min.js" (from "<http://my.server>")" at /var/www/html/akeneo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 139 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException(code: 0): No route found for \"GET /dist/main.min.js\" (from \"<http://my.server>") at /var/www/html/akeneo/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php:139, Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\ResourceNotFoundException(code: 0):  at /var/www/html/akeneo/var/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php:3585)"} []
```

I also encounter errors when I try the command:

```
yarn run webpack
```

Like :

```
Starting LESS compilation

‣ /var/www/html/akeneo/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Oro/Bundle/PimDataGridBundle/Resources/public/less/index.less
‣ /var/www/html/akeneo/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/src/Akeneo/Platform/Bundle/UIBundle/Resources/public/less/index.less


Updating form extensions.json
✓ Saved CSS to web/css/pim.css
Version: webpack 4.29.6
Time: 17079ms
Built at: 05/27/2019 6:03:50 PM
 2 assets
Entrypoint main = vendor.min.js main.min.js

ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/tests/front/unit/pimenrich/js/i18n.unit.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/akeneo/pim-community-dev/tests/front/unit/pimenrich/js/i18n.unit.ts(36,12)
      TS2554: Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.

ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts(1,7)
      TS1005: '>' expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts(1,14)
      TS1005: ';' expected.

ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /var/www/html/akeneo/pim-community-standard/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.ts(1,21)
      TS1005: ';' expected.
```

I've tried the following commands but it still doesn't work :

- composer install --optimize-autoloader --prefer-dist
- yarn install
- php bin/console --env=prod cache:clear --no-warmup
- php bin/console --env=prod pim:installer:assets --symlink --clean
- yarn run webpack

I would be very happy if there was someone who has found a solution to this problem ?

I've checked [how to i solve akeneo still loading after logged in main page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705009/how-to-i-solve-akeneo-still-loading-after-logged-in-main-page) but it hasn't resolved the problem.

Comment: What is your TypeScript compiler version ? (Run `tsc -v`)

Comment: Thanks :-)  Version 2.7.2

Comment: And, sorry I forgot to ask, your TypeScript version ? Maybe you can try to get the last version of these two.

Comment: I will try that, thanks again, for TypeScript Version : typescript@3.3.3333

Comment: I've found why it didn't work. It was because I've moved the content of the pim-community-standard directly into my-project.

Answer (score 0):

I've found why it didn't work. It was because I've moved the content of the pim-community-standard directly into my-project.

It had created two web folder, and lead to problems with redirections.

I've installed another projet my-project with 
- composer.phar
- pim-community-standard

And launch all the command from pim-community-standard.

Ccl : keep the exact same folder hierarchy if you install akeneo

Comment: Hi. I need your help